# Linux can't seem to detect my dedicated GPU on laptop

Tags: linux, arch-linux, laptop, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I am relatively new to Linux. I have installed Endeavour OS on my laptop (an HP Victus 16), and noticed underwhelming performance on apps like `waydroid`. It seems like linux is only detecting the iGPU in my system. When I run

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

it gives me the output

```
Providers: number : 0** !
```

Even going to Settings > About shows the graphics card as "AMD Renoir" only.

Running

```
lspci
```

shows the dGPU connected as:

```
Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev c1)**
```

but it seems like it doesn't work anywhere else?

Configuration of my laptop if it matters:

```
AMD Ryzen 5600h
16 GB RAM
AMD RX 5500M graphics
```

And the OS details:

```
Endeavour OS Linux x86_64
Kernel: 5.17.0-247-tkg-pds
```

Comment: Is your laptop hybrid? If yes, Have you installed any optimus graphics drivers?

Comment: Yes its a hybrid laptop, but an AMD + AMD system. And nope, havent installed optimus drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t so much to do for `amd` since most of the drivers are open source. You will want to install `xf86-video-amdgpu` if it isn’t installed already.

```
pacman -S xf86-video-amdgpu
```

You can also append `DRI_PRIME=1` to the program invocation

You can also use [Get-The-Right-AMD-Driver Website](https://discovery.endeavouros.com/amd-gpu/find-the-right-driver/2021/03/) to get some more drivers for the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `DRI_PRIME=1` to the program invocation.